# Lead to order relationship code first

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, foreign-key-relationship

Hi I'm trying to set up a code first relationship in Entity Framework 6 and was wondering how I do the following.

I have a `Lead` class and an `Order` class.  The `Order` class has to have a `Lead` but the `Lead` can be created without an order and doesn't have to be associated to one as a user may leave before making an order.

So my class structures are as such:

```
public Lead
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    ...other non-related properties
}

public Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int LeadID { get; set; }
    public virtual Lead Lead { get; set; }

    ...other non-related properties
}
```

And I tried to link them in the `OrderConfiguration()` using

```
this.HasRequired(o => o.Lead)
```

But this is wanting something like `WithOptional` or `Withrequired...` to follow it rather than the `HasForeignKey`

Is there any way to link these so that the `Lead` is auto-populated in the `Order` without the need for an `Order` property in the `Lead` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the attribute for the forgin key it have to look like these

```
[Key]
public int ID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Lead")]
public int LeadID { get; set; }
```

And in the Lead class

set the key too